# Maximum number of words plugin issue on  ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, ckeditor

I am trying to implement a word count feature on some of my text areas that have been converted to wswgs' using ckeditor tutorial found here: http://www.n7studios.co.uk/2010/03/01/ckeditor-word-count-plugin/. This tutorial uses a custom plugin to count words for ckeditor. I get the correct word count but I am not able to see the color change to red when I surpass the maximum number of words allowed. I have used firebug to see how my text area looks like after it has been transformed into a wswg using ckeditor but I don't see anything strange. Here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="JSContent" runat="server">
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.combobox.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js") %>"></script> <%-- Must be linked last --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".cke_editor").ckeditor({
            toolbar: 'custom'
        });

    });

<div class="form-row form-row-inline">
    <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AssignmentText, new { @name = "table", @class = "cke_editor", @style = "display:none", @onchange = "setDirty(true)" })%>
    <input name="tableWordCount" type="hidden" value="10" />
</div>
```

Here is the screen:

[image: ckeditor with the wordcount plugin]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good luck. The CKEditor has been plagued with bugs over the years; it sends shivers down my spine just thinking about my experiences with it. I would try a different editor if you can - something like TinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. `Html.TextAreaFor()` asp.net mvc helper method takes, as a parameter,  an object of html attributes as shown on the question code above. I originally had used the "name" property for the textarea so that it matches the "name property" on the ckeditor word count plugin. I had to instead use the "id" property.

ckeditor sample:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CKEditor Word Count Demonstration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label for="content">Content with 250 word limit</label>
            <textarea name="content" class="ckeditor">Lorem Ipsum.</textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="contentWordCount" value="250" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my new fixed code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="JSContent" runat="server">
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.combobox.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js") %>"></script> <%-- Must be linked last --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".cke_editor").ckeditor({
            toolbar: 'custom'
        });

    });

<div class="form-row form-row-inline">
    <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AssignmentText, new { @id = "taxta", @class = "cke_editor", @style = "display:none", @onchange = "setDirty(true)" })%>
    <input name="taxtaWordCount" type="hidden" value="10" />
</div>
```

So, the only thing I had to change is the "id" property. I hope this helps others. Again, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) was very helpful in delving through the html DOM and looking at how everything is rendered on the browser.